# Path finding in a finite grid

Tags: java, recursion, path-finding

I have a 7x7 grid (of a city). I want to travel from a starting point `(x1, y1)` to a destination point `(x2, y2)` and show the **path** as an output in the form of multiple `(x, y)` strings separated by comas. I want to do this using **RECURSION** and output true if the path exists and false otherwise.
How should I do that? I'm thinking of making 4 methods that check 4 directions. Any input would be appreciated.

For now, I have just implemented the constructor of my class:-

```
    map = new boolean[row][column];

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        { 
            map[i][j] = false; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming the city is a maze-type thing you can try this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm

Comment: Path finding actually is not a trial task, but there are many different algorithms. One of which is `A*`, which is a variation of `Dijkstra's Algorithm`. https://www.baeldung.com/java-a-star-pathfinding

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

/**
 * Dev Parzival
 * Date : 27/10/2020 Time : 18:28
 * I have a confidence about my life that comes from standing tall on my own two feet.
 */

public class Path {
    static PrintStream out=System.out;
    static boolean pathfound=false;
    //////////Main/////////
    public static void main(String $[]){
        boolean arr[][]=new boolean[5][5];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++) {
                if (i==0)
                    arr[i][j] = true;
                if(j==arr[0].length-1)
                    arr[i][j]=true;
            }
        travel(arr,0,0,arr.length-1,arr[0].length-1);
        if(pathfound)
            out.println("Path is found");
        else
            out.println("Path is not found");
    }
    
    static boolean travel(boolean a[][],int r,int c,int targetR,int targetC){
    //Target is found
    if(r==targetR && c==targetC){
        pathfound=true;
    }
    //South
    if(!pathfound && r+1<a.length)
        if(a[r+1][c]){
            a[r+1][c]=false;
            pathfound=travel(a,r+1,c,targetR,targetC);
        }
    //North
    if(!pathfound && r-1>=0)
        if(a[r-1][c]){
            a[r-1][c]=false;
            pathfound=travel(a,r-1,c,targetR,targetC);
        }
    //East
    if(!pathfound && c+1<a[0].length)
        if(a[r][c+1]){
            a[r][c+1]=false;
            pathfound=travel(a,r,c+1,targetR,targetC);
        }
    //West
    if(!pathfound && c-1>=0)
        if(a[r][c-1]){
            a[r][c-1]=false;
            pathfound=travel(a,r,c-1,targetR,targetC);
        }
        if(pathfound)
            out.println(r+" "+c);
        return pathfound;
    }
}
```

I will advice make a copy of original array so values will not be modified.
I have tested above code works fine .This approach is known as `flood fill` .Search more about `depth first search` in `graph.`

Comment: in the first for loop I am setting the path . I have chosen 5x5 matrix u can give any size as u wish. in travel first argument is the grid then starting row and column after that its target row and column..

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was wondering what should I do if I'm making a method such as goSouthWest where it solves the problem only for going in a south west direction using recursion, any idea would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: basically, I aim to make 4 methods. `goSouthWest`, `goSouthEast`, `goNorthWest`, `goNorthEast`. Each of these methods are accessed through a method `givePath` which basically checks if **destRow** or **destCol** is less than, equal to or greater than **startRow** or **startCol** and calls one of the above 4 methods to solve the problem. 

Each method solves it recursively and output a string in a form of **(x, y) (x, y) (x, y) ...** where `(x, y)` is one step of the path.

Comment: I guess that u want to go in 8 directions from a cell north ,south,east , west,  north east,north west, south east and south west?

Comment: yes, this code is basically divided into sections of directions

Comment: @Nzed I have fixed bug from above code and for traveling also diagonally I have posed my source.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

/**
 * Dev Parzival
 * Date : 27/10/2020 Time : 18:28
 * I have a confidence about my life that comes from standing tall on my own two feet.
 */

public class Path {
    static PrintStream out=System.out;
    static boolean pathfound=false;
    //////////Main/////////
    public static void main(String $[]){
        boolean arr[][]=new boolean[5][5];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++) {
                if (i==j)
                    arr[i][j] = true;
//                if(j==arr[0].length-1)
//                    arr[i][j]=true;
            }
        travel(arr,0,0,arr.length-1,arr[0].length-1);
        if(pathfound)
            out.println("Path is found");
        else
            out.println("Path is not found");
    }

    static boolean travel(boolean a[][],int r,int c,int targetR,int targetC){

        //Target is found
        if(r==targetR && c==targetC){
            pathfound=true;
        }
        //South
        if(!pathfound && r+1<a.length)
            if(a[r+1][c]){
                a[r+1][c]=false;
                pathfound=travel(a,r+1,c,targetR,targetC);
            }
        //North
        if(!pathfound && r-1>=0)
            if(a[r-1][c]){
                a[r-1][c]=false;
                pathfound=travel(a,r-1,c,targetR,targetC);
            }
        //East
        if(!pathfound && c+1<a[0].length)
            if(a[r][c+1]){
                a[r][c+1]=false;
                pathfound=travel(a,r,c+1,targetR,targetC);
            }
        //West
        if(!pathfound && c-1>=0)
            if(a[r][c-1]){
                a[r][c-1]=false;
                pathfound=travel(a,r,c-1,targetR,targetC);
            }
        //North-West
        if(!pathfound && c-1>=0 && r-1>=0)
            if(a[r-1][c-1]){
                a[r-1][c-1]=false;
                pathfound=travel(a,r-1,c-1,targetR,targetC);
            }
        //Noth-East
        if(!pathfound && c+1<a[0].length && r-1>=0)
            if(a[r-1][c+1]){
                a[r-1][c+1]=false;
                pathfound=travel(a,r-1,c+1,targetR,targetC);
            }
        //South-East
        if(!pathfound && c+1<a[0].length && r+1<a.length)
            if(a[r+1][c+1]){
                a[r+1][c+1]=false;
                pathfound=travel(a,r+1,c+1,targetR,targetC);
            }
        //South-West
        if(!pathfound && c-1>=0 && r+1<a.length)
            if(a[r+1][c-1]){
                a[r+1][c-1]=false;
                pathfound=travel(a,r+1,c-1,targetR,targetC);
            }
        //Print the cell position
        if(pathfound)
            out.println(r+" "+c);
        return pathfound;
    }
}
```

Above code will find a path between **starting cell** and the **destination** cell if path exists.

**Output it generates:**

```
4 4
3 3
2 2
1 1
0 0
Path is found
```

Comment: Along with searching horizontally and vertically it also searches diagonally.

Comment: just to confirm, are your diagonal direction methods correct? as in ``South-West``, **[r+1][c-1]** basically tells to move up a row, and step back a column, which is nothing but ``North-West``. If this is an error, it's also in other methods. If not, could you explain what's happening here?

Comment: @Nzed suppose you are at cell `[4,4]` and target is at `[5,3]` then `[r+1][c-1]` its telling `move down in a row` and step back a column.